Modifying range in Traffic light Iconset in Openpyxl
I have a sample data in excel like as below
cust_id,avg_purchase
1,0.2
2,0.5
3,100
4,9
5,1
6,31
7,9.5
8, "No purchase"
9, "No purchase"

I would like to do the below using Openpyxl
a) Insert traffic light symbol for column B that is 'avg_purchse' based on the below criteria
   if avg_purchase <= 8 then "Yellow"
   if avg_purchase >8 and avg_purchase <=10 then "green"
   else (avg_purchase) > 10 then "red"

So, I tried the below
from openpyxl.formatting.rule import IconSet, FormatObject
first = FormatObject(type='num', val=0)
second = FormatObject(type='num', val=8)
third = FormatObject(type='num', val=10)
iconset = IconSet(iconSet='3TrafficLights1', cfvo=[third, second, first], showValue=None, percent=None, reverse=None)
# assign the icon set to a rule
from openpyxl.formatting.rule import Rule
rule = Rule(type='iconSet', iconSet=iconset)
sheet.conditional_formatting.add("B2:B11111", rule)
workbook.save('wb2e.xlsx') 

However, it doesn't work the way I expect it. May be I don't understand how to define the limits correctly
I expect my output to be like as below


The default traffic light color order is red, yellow, green. It might be green, yellow, red in reverse order reverse=True. But yellow always will be in the middle. Thus yellow cannot be a border case in a traffic light rule.

but when we do manually in excel, it does allow us to set colors and range as per our wish.

Meaning, we can set even set Yellow as first color for values from 0-8. but using openpyxl we cannot?

Not possible using openpyxl as it is now. It only supports either rule = IconSetRule('3TrafficLights1', 'num', [0, 8, 10], showValue=None, percent=None, reverse=None) or the same using ...reverse=True). Both will have yellow in the middle.
